# Resize event for multiple elements at different times

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where different elements need to be re-sized by JavaScript when the window is re-sized.

Currently for each element I am simply attaching a new event like so:

```
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){ self.resize(MyEl);}, false );
```

I'm starting to think this isn't a smart idea, because say i have to resize 50 elements, i am currently attaching 50 events (gross exaggeration, but you can see how it isn't a smart design). Not to mention, when i remove the element, the event is still there!

So i am wondering what would be a better way to handle the resize event so it will then process different resize functions that i define but can equally remove said functions when they are no longer relevant.

What is considered a good approach for something like this so i then only need one event attached.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize',function(){ self.resizeEverything();}, false );`?

Comment: Is that a question ?

Comment: It's an answer which is so obvious that I guess I'm missing something in your question ;) You wanted to resize everything at once instead of element by element, so I replaced `self.resize(MyEl)` with `self.resizeEverything()`.

Comment: Well not all elements need resizing for one (fixed in size), and some have different maths applied to calculating their height, such as finding their offsetTop to their parent and then "filling" the remainder of the height. Others resize without the need of javascript anyway such as inheriting parent height etc. So i need to control what elements and what maths to use to resize with.

Comment: Yes, but instead of registering 50 event handlers, you can resize 50 elements in `resizeEverything`... On the other hand, this might be a case of **premature optimization**. I would not expect that registering 1000 event handlers is significantly worse than doing 1000 things in some other manner (until proven otherwise, at least)

Comment: It's not so much optimization here, its more to do with removing clutter, because at the moment, if i remove an element the event is still attached, because the event is not attached to the element, so it's not auto removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an object to map an element to function. For example:

```
var toResize = {'#banner': self.bigResizer, '.ads': self.smallResizer};
```

Then you can easily dynamically add/remove elements and their resize function.

```
toResize['#footer'] = self.bigResizer;
delete toResize['#banner'];
```

Then in your event handler you'd do something like:

```
for (var sel in toResize) {
  if (toResize[sel]) {
    toResize[sel].call(self, document.querySelector(sel));
  }
}
```

Comment: Bit confused by the syntax, what does document.querySelector and call do?

Could i not do something like this in the loop `toResize[sel]()` which basically calls the function, though i would need to still inform that function which element i am wanting to resize?

Comment: `document.querySelector` is selecting the actual element so you can pass it to the document as per your example. That said, this is overly simplified (the class selectors would need `document.querySelectorAll` etc.) and ideally your resize functions would take a selector and not just the element.  Your question only had one line of code so there's quite a few blanks to fill in...

Comment: Well ideally i want to pass the element or it's id to get the element and a function to call to do stuff with that element. Whilst needing a way to remove it from the list when i remove the element etc.

Comment: @Dave As far as I can tell this meets all of your requirements. I provided an example for every case above as best as I could, but without seeing your code it's hard to tell you where to do what, but theoretically this will work.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try implementing it and see where it takes me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, adding separate events for each element is the correct approach compared to what I will explain below. The reason is that browser will run the event function when its time comes, so the browser won't freeze.

Also, I am sure you know it already, you can remove the event function if it was a single function instead of anonymous function. So, turning the system into that style would be helpful.

---

Another approach, but this might freeze your browser whenever the window is resized.

Define an array. Each item of array is an htmlElement.

`var elementsToBeResized = [];`

Define a single function that receives the resize event for elements.

```
function element_resize( elIndex ){
    var htmlElement = elementsToBeResized[ elIndex ];

    if( !document.body.contains( htmlElement ) ){
        elementsToBeResized[ elIndex ] = null;
        return;
    }

    // ... do your resizing things ...
}
```

When window is resized, call a function that loops over the array `elementsToBeResized`. And instead of adding new event, either replace a `null` item in `elementsToBeResized`, or append it.

But do not forget, because all events are called sequentially without a break, it might create freezing issue as I am telling third time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply resize all the elements in one event handler.

The list of elements would need to be maintained in global object of some form though.

Using jQuery, for example:

```
var $all = $('div')
$( window ).resize( function(){ 

    $all.each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        // individual element resize logic goes here e.g.
        // $(this).myresizefunc();
  })
});
```

jsfiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/jsheridan390/aLdap6j8/

Comment: Thanks, though i do not use jQuery.